# How to install PHP 8 on XAMPP

Tags: php, apache, xampp, php-8

I'm trying to update my PHP version to the brand new PHP 8. I have followed simular steps as [this](https://webhostingmedia.net/update-xampp-php-version-windows/) tutorial. But now the following error is shown:

```
12:06:23  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
12:06:23  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
12:06:23  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
12:06:23  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
12:06:23  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
12:06:23  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
12:06:23  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
```

**Notice:** I have used a brand new XAMPP instalation version 7.2.33.

I can't find the solution for my issue.

**Edit**
It is saying that I need to look into the Log files hower they are completly empty since it's a brand new installation.

This is my `httpd-xampp.conf`:

```
<IfModule env_module>
    SetEnv MIBDIRS "C:/xampp/php/extras/mibs"
    SetEnv MYSQL_HOME "\\xampp\\mysql\\bin"
    SetEnv OPENSSL_CONF "C:/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.cnf"
    SetEnv PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR "\\xampp\\php"
    SetEnv PHPRC "\\xampp\\php"
    SetEnv TMP "\\xampp\\tmp"
</IfModule>

#
# PHP-Module setup
#
LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/php8ts.dll"
LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/libpq.dll"
LoadModule php8_module "C:/xampp/php/php8apache2_4.dll"
LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/libsqlite3.dll"

<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.phps$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
</FilesMatch>

#
# PHP-CGI setup
#
#<FilesMatch "\.php$">
#    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-cgi
#</FilesMatch>
#<IfModule actions_module>
#    Action application/x-httpd-php-cgi "/php-cgi/php-cgi.exe"
#</IfModule>


<IfModule php8_module>
    PHPINIDir "C:/xampp/php"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_module>
    AddType text/html .php .phps
</IfModule>

ScriptAlias /php-cgi/ "C:/xampp/php/"
<Directory "C:/xampp/php">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all denied
    <Files "php-cgi.exe">
          Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/xampp/cgi-bin">
    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        SetHandler cgi-script
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.phps$">
        SetHandler None
    </FilesMatch>
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/xampp">
    <IfModule php8_module>
        <Files "status.php">
            php_admin_flag safe_mode off
        </Files>
    </IfModule>
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
</Directory>

<IfModule alias_module>
    Alias /licenses "C:/xampp/licenses/"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/licenses">
        Options +Indexes
        <IfModule autoindex_color_module>
            DirectoryIndexTextColor  "#000000"
            DirectoryIndexBGColor "#f8e8a0"
            DirectoryIndexLinkColor "#bb3902"
            DirectoryIndexVLinkColor "#bb3902"
            DirectoryIndexALinkColor "#bb3902"
        </IfModule>
        Require local
        ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
   </Directory>

    Alias /phpmyadmin "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin/"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Require local
        ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
    </Directory>

    Alias /webalizer "C:/xampp/webalizer/"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/webalizer">
        <IfModule php8_module>
            <Files "webalizer.php">
                php_admin_flag safe_mode off
            </Files>
        </IfModule>
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Require local
        ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Can you post your `httpd-xampp.conf`?

Comment: Why are you asking here before you followed up on the leads you already have? The error message says "Press the Logs button to view error logs and check the Windows Event Viewer for more clues". So do that!

Comment: Please look at the edit I have made

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Rewriting `php8_module` to `php_module` (all occurrences) in

"httpd-xampp.conf" file solved the `Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly` problem for me :)

Comment: That worked for me too. Thanks for posting it.

Answer (score 5):

IN https://windows.php.net/download#php-8.0

What is very important you have to download the "Thread Safe" version. otherwise you have no "php8apache2_4.dll" and you need that so that php8 works with apache in XAMPP.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  None of the above answers applied to me because the regular php download versions did not have the extras folder and also not the php8...dll files.  However, even with the 'Thread Safe' version, the mibs folder is not there.

Answer (score 4):

Running  PHP 8 on XAMPP is easy now since XAMPP new version released with PHP 8 update. Install XAMPP, and run first PHP program using XAMPP Server on localhost. Following are the steps:

- Download and Install XAMPP
- Create a new project in XAMPP and add your PHP program
- Open XAMPP and run your first PHP program

**Download and Install XAMPP**

**Step 1**: Go to the Apache Friends website and download XAMPP Server (supporting PHP 8). Apache Friends is the official website to download XAMPP:

[Download XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/download.html)

**Step 2**: After downloading, install it.
You can install it at any location. We installed XAMPP i.e. C: drive,

Create a new project in XAMPP

**Step 3**: Now, go to *htdocs* folder in Xampp folder and create your project folder.

Here, a folder AmitProject created, as in the below screenshot:

Follow [this](https://studyopedia.com/php/run-php-8-program-xampp-server/) tutorial and you won't need to update any settings shown above.

Comment: I have xampp already installed

Comment: This isn't a good answer - OP is trying to upgrade an existing XAMPP to PHP8

Comment: This is a good answer in fact it's the best answer - just upgrade your old software!

Answer (score 1):

This error is the result of an xampp misconfiguration for the new php version (means wrong entries in xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf).

Luckily, you can check the configuration of the apache server with this shell command:

```
c:/xampp/apache/bin/httpd.exe -t
```

(Replace the drive letter with your installation drive letter, also change the xampp folder if you have xampp installed in a custom folder.)

If you see `Syntax OK` php should work basically (don't forget to copy/adjust the php.ini file). If not, the output of `httpd.exe -t` offer useful hints what should be changed in httpd-xampp.conf.

Answer (score 0):

1. rename old php dir to phpX
2. Download the needed version of PHP  + dev pack, ex.: https://windows.php.net/download#php-8.0
3. extract to xampp/php the donwloaded archives
4. if old php configs matters for you, copy phpX/php.ini to php/
5. extract into xampp, rewrite the referring phpOld lines in httpd-xampp.config

- Instead of phpX_module, use just php_module

6. if problem persists, running xampp_start gives `PHP load error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.` then also download new apache version...

- don't forget to put at thier place the httpd.conf, httpd-ssl.conf, httpd-xampp.conf

Or instead of downloading the modules separately, just do a new XAMPP installation with the desired version and copy php+apache dirs, then unistall the old one. From the old apache dir get the httpd*.conf files or correct their paths.

Answer (score 0):

I choose this way

Back up your XAMPP and htdocs files,
then uninstall XAMPP,
Download New XAMPP Version,
Install XAMPP
configure the path to your back-up htdocs files or Project Files -> httpd.config

you should find this so that you can customize the path

```
DocumentRoot "D:\PROJECT"
<Directory "D:\PROJECT">
```