# tried updating my php in xampp now i keep getting this error

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp, localhost

i am running a website on a local host was trying to update my php version to php8 64 bit, so i followed this guide at first:https://www.wpblog.com/update-php-version-in-xampp/#1

but in the end i got this error:

```
23:22:13  [Apache]  Attempting to start Apache app...

23:22:13  [Apache]  Status change detected: running

23:22:14  [Apache]  Status change detected: stopped

23:22:14  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.

23:22:14  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 

23:22:14  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.

23:22:14  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check

23:22:14  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues

23:22:14  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this

23:22:14  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
```

then i searched for a similar topic that might has some awnsers like:
[How to install PHP 8 on XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65072518/how-to-install-php-8-on-xampp)

unfortunatly this coulndt fix it either :(

this is my `httpd-xampp.conf`

```
#
# XAMPP settings
#

<IfModule env_module>
    SetEnv MIBDIRS "C:/xampp/php/extras/mibs"
    SetEnv MYSQL_HOME "\\xampp\\mysql\\bin"
    SetEnv OPENSSL_CONF "C:/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.cnf"
    SetEnv PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR "\\xampp\\php"
    SetEnv PHPRC "\\xampp\\php"
    SetEnv TMP "\\xampp\\tmp"
</IfModule>

#
# PHP-Module setup
#
LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/php8ts.dll"
LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/libpq.dll"
LoadModule php8_module "C:/xampp/php/php8apache2_4.dll"

<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.phps$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
</FilesMatch>

#
# PHP-CGI setup
#
#<FilesMatch "\.php$">
#    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-cgi
#</FilesMatch>
#<IfModule actions_module>
#    Action application/x-httpd-php-cgi "/php-cgi/php-cgi.exe"
#</IfModule>


<IfModule php8_module>
    PHPINIDir "C:/xampp/php"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_module>
    AddType text/html .php .phps
</IfModule>

ScriptAlias /php-cgi/ "C:/xampp/php/"
<Directory "C:/xampp/php">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all denied
    <Files "php-cgi.exe">
          Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/xampp/cgi-bin">
    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        SetHandler cgi-script
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.phps$">
        SetHandler None
    </FilesMatch>
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/xampp">
    <IfModule php8_module>
        <Files "status.php">
            php_admin_flag safe_mode off
        </Files>
    </IfModule>
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
</Directory>

<IfModule alias_module>
    Alias /licenses "C:/xampp/licenses/"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/licenses">
        Options +Indexes
        <IfModule autoindex_color_module>
            DirectoryIndexTextColor  "#000000"
            DirectoryIndexBGColor "#f8e8a0"
            DirectoryIndexLinkColor "#bb3902"
            DirectoryIndexVLinkColor "#bb3902"
            DirectoryIndexALinkColor "#bb3902"
        </IfModule>
        Require local
        ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
   </Directory>

    Alias /phpmyadmin "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin/"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Require local
        ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
    </Directory>

    Alias /webalizer "C:/xampp/webalizer/"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/webalizer">
        <IfModule php_module>
            <Files "webalizer.php">
                php_admin_flag safe_mode off
            </Files>
        </IfModule>
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Require local
        ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

i tried Rewriting `php8_module` to `php_module` but this had no effect.

i really dont know what else to do now please help :(

Comment: I was tired too, I can suggest you Laragon, it's the best, you can use multiple apache, PHP, database version, I'm in love with this. Xammp have several issues, the same issue faced by you may be because of skype, or some other application.